# How to display a friendly name in URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

This is my new resource in routes file :

```
resources :staticpage do
    collection do
            get :aboutus 
            get :snacks 
            get :contactus
    end
end
```

this generates my urls   `localhost:3000/staticpage/aboutus`     `localhost:3000/staticpage/snacks/`      `localhost:3000/staticpage/contactus`

Instead of this complex url i want to have `localhost:3000/aboutus` , `localhost:3000/snacks/`  `localhost:3000/contactus` in the URL.

using gem can change my action name, but i want to alter "controllername/action" to a simple string. 
What modification should be done in the routes path declaration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [routes documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes), you will need to define the routes manually (like David Underwood's answer). However, there is an even better way to do it:

```
#config/routes.rb
static = %w(aboutus snacks contactus)
static.each do |page|
   get page.to_sym, to: "staticpage#show", page: page
end

#app/controllers/staticpages_controller.rb
def show
    page = params[:page]
    render "staticpages#{page}"
end
```

Comment: why not just `render params[:page]` ?

Comment: Can do - I was just recommending what I would look at. It can ofc be refactored as required

Comment: hi @RichPeck. I don't have any show action. have 3 separate actions aboutus ,snacks, contactus.  

I tried with def aboutus but the page = params[:page] returns nil.

Comment: If all your actions will do the same job, keep it DRY by putting them into the same method. It should pass the `page` param when you hit the route - can you look at your logs?

Comment: Yes, @RichPeck ! I got your point. 
just added the show action and configured routes. but where I am supposed to redirect in link_to 'about us', '#' , link_to 'snacks', '#' ???

Comment: `<%= link_to "About Us", aboutus_path %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write matchers for each route like this:

```
get 'aboutus', to: 'staticpage#aboutus'
get 'snacks', to: 'staticpage#snacks'
get 'contactus', to: 'staticpage#contactus'
```

Note that you don't need the `resources` or `collection` block if you do this.

Comment: I know this way, but this does not follow the REST architecture!
I was doing : 
get 'aboutus', to: 'staticpages#aboutus', as: 'aboutus' 
I want to do with resources :controller_name  structure ! 
any ways ?

Comment: Named static pages aren't RESTful in the first place. REST is great for resources that are frequently modified, but you don't have to apply it everywhere.